# ArrayList's containsAll returning wrong value

Tags: java, android, string, list

Let's say:

```
a = ["s", "i", "n", "e", "d"];
b = ["s", "e", "n", "d"];
```

(`a` and `b` are of type `List<String>`)

How can I determine if all the letters in `b` are contained in `a`? -- not necessarily in order (In this case, it's true since `[s,e,n,d]` is in `a` and `b`)

Using `a.containsAll(b)` does not always work!

Another example:

```
a=["b", "a", "z", "z", "z"]
b=["a", "a", "b", "b"]
```

Here I want the result to be `false` since `[a,a,b,b]` does not appear in any sort of order in `a`, but using `a.containsAll(b)` will return `true`!

Comment: So why not match the size of both lists. If equal then go for containsAll.

Comment: what do you mean by "fix"? if you want your own logic simply write a function that does it

Comment: I guess I meant is there a way to alter containsAll --- like a.containsAll(b, 1) where the 1 means that it will scan each letter only once

Comment: Ah I like naveen's answer

Comment: @PankajKumar the issue with that is I may also have a=[b,a,n,z,z,z] and b=[b,a,n,a,n,a] and it will return true since a contains b, a, n

Comment: What are the possible characters? Is it only small-case letter? The idea is to count each letters in `a`, then subtract it from `b`. If all counts are 0 or positive, then `a` contains all `b` (note that this include the case of an empty string `b`). Else, if one or more are negatives, then no.

Comment: i rephrased the question. letter a-z only and only small case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private boolean containsAll(List<?> a, List<?> b) {
    // List doesn't support remove(), use ArrayList instead
    ArrayList<Object> x = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayList<Object> y = new ArrayList<Object>();

    x.addAll(a);
    y.addAll(b);
    for (Object o : y) {
        if (!x.remove(o)) // an element in B is not in A!
            return false;
    }
    return true;          // all elements in B are also in A
}
```

The idea is to remove each letter in `b` from `a`. When you try to remove a letter that is not in `a`, then it's confirmed that `a` doesn't contain all letters in `b`.

(`remove()` will return `true` if the element exists, otherwise `false`)

Answer (score 2):

> Simply add your whole String list to new String variable by using **for each**
>   And find the one String variable value contains the other String or not, by using **[.contains()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)**

```
List<String> a = ["b","a","n"];
List<String> b = ["b","a","n","a","n","a"];

String newA = null;
String newB = null;

for(String strA : a) {
  newA += strA;
}
for(String strB : b) {
  newB += strB;
}

if(newA.contains(newB))
  return True;
else
  return False;
```

[Reference for String **.contains()**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm)

Comment: but a possible problem: I don't want to check if the strings are equal. I want to check if one string is contained in the other string

Comment: @user2456977 modified my answer, review it. and follow this example URL http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm

Comment: I read about String.contains() but it won't work properly: it only works in sequence. but if a=[s,i,e,n,d] and b=[s,e,n,d] String.contains() will return false! even though "send" is contained in 'a'

Comment: a=[s,i,n,e,d] and b=[s,e,n,d]. in this case it will display false? right... u want character positions also...

Comment: right but in this case I want it to return true since in fact all the letters in 'b' are in 'a'

Comment: sorry for not being clear

Comment: i rephrased the question if you want to take another look. things should be more clear now.

Comment: Upvote for your answer. Just needed sorting

Answer (score 2):

Remove from the bigger list all the elements that not appear in the smaller list and equal them. If they are equal then the smaller list is contained in the bigger:

```
static List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("b");
    add("a");
    add("n");
    add("z");
    add("z");
    add("z");
    }};
static List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("b");
    add("a");
    add("n");
    add("a");
    add("n");
    add("a");
}};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(deepContains(list1, list2)) 
        System.out.println("List2 is contained in List1"); 
}

public static boolean deepContains(List<String> one, List<String> two){     
    if (one == null && two == null){
        return true;
    }

    if((one == null && two != null) 
      || one != null && two == null){
        return false;
    }

    //to avoid messing the order and elements of the lists we will use a copy
    one = new ArrayList<String>(one);
    two = new ArrayList<String>(two);
    //This removes from one all the elements not contained in two
    one.retainAll(two); 
    int a = one.size();
    int b = two.size();

    //one has lesser elements than two, for sure two is not contained in one
    if(a < b) return false;

    //one has the same number of elements of two, check if they are the same
    if(a == b){
        Collections.sort(one);
        Collections.sort(two);      
        return one.equals(two); 
    }

    //one has more elements than two. Remove duplicate elements
    //and check for equality
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(one);
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(two);

    if(set1.size() == set2.size()){
        one = new ArrayList<String>(set1);
        two = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
        Collections.sort(one);
        Collections.sort(two);      
        return one.equals(two); 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your method is the best except for the last part. set1.size won't always be equal to set2.size. For instance: a=[b,a,n,z,z,z,a,n,a] and b=[b,a,n,a,n,a] should return true because banana is present in a. It won't return true in your method because after the removal of duplicate elements banz will be present in a and ban will be present in b, and this will cause it to fail.

Comment: upvote for the first part of your method up to the last part

Comment: Z won't be there because of the retainAll, shouldn't it?

Comment: You're right, missed that. It should work. I tried your code but it didn't work for me. I'll look over it again.

Comment: Yours is the correct answer. It does work. Sorry for that, don't think I had enough coffee today

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that works for any collection of any type:

```
private <E> boolean containsAllIncludingDuplicates(Collection<E> container,
        Collection<E> items) {

    Set<E> checkedItems = new HashSet<>();
    for (E item : items) {
        if (checkedItems.add(item)
                && Collections.frequency(container, item) < Collections
                        .frequency(items, item)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The use of the Set ensures that the frequency check is not repeated multiple times when there are duplicates in items.